# Eclipse keeps launching Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I am writing an android project to read file content and show the content of a text file by a Toast. Eclipse keeps launching the project. When I close Eclipse, it is not responding and I have to force Eclipse to close by Task Manager.

Comment: What about sharing your code?

Comment: Post your logcat with related code.

Comment: There is nothing in Logcat and console

Comment: I realize that eventually some program takes too long to launch on the emulator(about an hour) but the others can launch immediately although they do not differ a lot in size

Comment: please show your code...

Answer (score 0):

`Eclipse keeps lauching the project. When I close eclipse...`
This is unclear for me. Why do you close Eclipse when the project is being launched?

When Eclipse stops, do you see something like: 27% - Launching delegate?
(This is a common error and there's a fix)

Comment: I meant that Eclipse keeps lauching the project forever.

Comment: And I didn't see anything like 27% - Launching delegate when Eclipse stops.

Comment: Did you try the solution described in the blog post to see if it solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same few times, eclipse lauching stopped at 100% and then was keeping this state forever.

Those are possible solutions:

1. run console and 1) adb kill-server 2) adb start-server after which launching will be terminated. Then launch project again - all should work now
2. Go to your project Run Configurations, delete old configurations and let eclipse create a new one while attempting to launch it next time